# Trying to get VBA to pull in data from Zillow

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding and have been trying to figure out how to extract specific data from zillow and import it into excel. To be honest I am pretty lost trying to figure this out and I have been looking throughout the form and other online videos, but I haven't had any luck.

Here is the link to the website I am using https://www.zillow.com/new-york-ny/home-values/

I am looking to pull all the numbers into excel so I can run some calculations. If someone could help me just pull in the Zillow Home Value Index of $660,000 into excel, I feel that I can figure out the rest.

This is the code from the website

```
<ul class="value-info-list" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1529698944920_2626">
<li id="yui_3_18_1_1_1529698944920_2625">
    <!-- TODO: need zillow logo icon here -->
    <!-- <span class="zss-logo-color"><span class="zss-font-icon"></span></span> -->

    <span class="value" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1529698944920_2624">
        $660,000
    </span>

    <span class="info zsg-fineprint"> ZHVI

    </span>
```

I tried getElementsByTagName getElementById and getElemenByClass The id is confusing me since I want to be able to enter any town into excel and it will search on zillow for the data on the web page. All the id tags are different so if I search by id in this code it will not work for other towns. I used the Class tag and was able to get some of the data I was looking for.

This is the code I came up with It pulls into the text box the $660,000. The Range function is working and putting the text box data into excel. This is pulling a bunch of strings which I was able to pull out the $660,000, but the way the sting is set up Im not sure how to pull the remaining data, such as the 1 year forecast  "yr_forcast" is the cell range I want to pull the data into excel.

```
Sub SearchBot1()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument 'holds document object for internet explorer

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://www.zillow.com/new-york-ny/home-values/"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
objIE.document.getElementById("local-search").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Value & ", " & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Value

'click the 'go' button
  Set the_input_elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
  For Each input_element In the_input_elements
   If input_element.getAttribute("name") = "SubmitButton" Then

    input_element.Click
    Exit For
End If
Next input_element

'wait again for the browser
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'price for home

 Set Doc = objIE.document
  Dim cclass As String
   cclass = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("value-info-list")(0).innerText)
   MsgBox cclass
    Dim aclass As Variant
    aclass = Split(cclass, " ")
    Range("Market_Price").Value = aclass(0)
    Range("yr_forecast").Value = aclass(5)
 'close the browser
   objIE.Quit
 End Sub
```

If you need anymore information please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? There are myriad resources for web scraping with VBA here on SO, as well as the internet more broadly.  You'll probably be looking for things like `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById`

Comment: I have tried using getElementsByClass since that = "value" and it is consistent with any town I would search for. The issue is there are so many "Values" idk how to delineate the one I'm trying to pull from. I also tried getElementsByID but the id changes for each town I would want to look up.@BruceWayne

Comment: can you post the code you've tried, and the results it gives?

Comment: I updated the post with the code I was using @BruceWayne

Answer (score 0):

The value you want is the first element with className `value`. You can use `querySelector` to apply a CSS selector of `.value`, where `"."` is the selector for class, to get this value.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Const URL As String = "https://www.zillow.com/new-york-ny/home-values/"
    html.body.innerHTML = GetHTML(URL)
    Debug.Print html.querySelector(".value").innerText
End Sub

Public Function GetHTML(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    GetHTML = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
End Function
```

You could also use:

```
Debug.Print html.getElementsByClassName("value")(0).innerText
```

---

**Current webpage value:**

[image: webpage]

---

**Code output:**

[image: code output]